# Logical reasoning at Klarna interview

Tags: reasoning

I get this reasoning question in Klarna pre test. Please help me to solve this. [Question is in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdsgM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct 'B' is the answer
1). Center 3 Dots , that is the 3rd column Will stay the same
2). 4th and 5th Column moves from right to left one at a time, as soon 2 black dots merged it will be come white, if the black moves it will become white again
3). Try the entire sequence filled with Numbers ( 1 to 10 ) in place of black dots to avoid confusion and solve the problem

if you have more questions, please do let me know

Comment: Merging and turning white/Separating and Turning black is the key pattern we need to observe.

Answer (score 0):

The correct Answer is **B**

Its because the middle column black squares remain constant while the two right columns move left. When they merge they become white. At separation restore to black.